# For the first person( I ,We) we use simple tense form and for the third person (he,she) we use verb+s, but which tense form we use for second peson?

Tags: tense, verbs

For first person:
1) I study during night
For third person: 
2) He studies in night
For second person:
3)You must continue your studies.

Why in this sentence is the third person verb form used?

Comment: I can't understand your question completely; which sentence uses the third person verb form? Only the 2º one as far as I can see.

I'm not completely sure but you may possibly be talking about the noun phrase *your studies* acting as a direct object of the verb *continue*, right?

The "verb" *studies* is not acting as a verb there; it is acting as a noun, the plural form of *study*, **study** can have two different usages: As a noun:
*I love math studies!* - As a verb: *I study math.*

In: You must continue your studies - *studies* isn't a verb; instead, it is a noun in its plural form.

Answer (score 1):

Third person singular is different; all the others are the same. First person: I study, we study; second person: you (singular) study, you (plural) study; third person: **he/she/it studies**, they study.

An excerpt from [Cengage.com](http://college.cengage.com/english/raimes/digitalkeys/keyshtml/subject2.htm), please see the entire page:

```
Subject-Verb Agreement
Simple Present Base Forms:  like    have    be      do

Singular                 
1st person: I               like    have    am      do
2nd person: you             like    have    are     do
3rd person: he, she, it     likes   has     is      does

Plural               
1st person: we              like    have    are     do
2nd person: you             like    have    are     do
3rd person: they            like    have    are     do
```